# I need help searching a string for a substring while avoiding words that contain the substring

Tags: c, string, substring, string-comparison

I'm writing a code that uses a keyword to find songs that contain the keyword in their name. I ran into an issue where a larger word contains the keyword (searched the list using you, found an option that has your). How do I alter my code to ignore the larger words?
I tried to use strstr() and compare the returned value with the length of the keyword, as well as, copying the length of the keyword into another string and comparing that. I'm not really sure how else to go about it, and appreciate any help.
I can't include a photo yet so here's a link to it

```
printf("Enter the keyword: ");

scanf("%s", keyWord);


convert_to_lowercase(keyWord, keyWordLower);

songCount = 0;

for (i = 0; i < songNum; i++) {
strcpy(listInfoLower, (listInfo + i)->name);
convert_to_lowercase(listInfoLower, listInfoLower);


if (strstr(listInfoLower, keyWordLower) != NULL) { 
    songCount++;
}
}
if (songCount == 0) {


printf("No songs with %s in database\n", keyWord);

}

else if (songCount != 0) {
printf("%d songs with %s\n", songCount, keyWord);


for (i = 0; i < songNum; i++) {


strcpy(listInfoLower, listInfo[i].name);


convert_to_lowercase(listInfoLower, listInfoLower);


if (strstr(listInfoLower, keyWordLower) != NULL) {
       

 printf("%s(%d) by %s, US(%d)\n", (listInfo + i)->name, (listInfo 
              + i)->year, (listInfo + i)->artist, (listInfo + i)-> 
              us_rank);


}
}
}
```

Comment: please add some code, not picture...

Comment: "searching a string for a substring while avoiding words that contain the substring" I don't understand what this means. Could you give some examples of the input to your program and exactly what should happen as a result?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you understand how to post your code correctly.

Comment: So for example if I search using the word you, it should return 3 song names that have you (Without You, Shape of You, Just the Way You Are). Instead it is returning 4 song names (The previous three and Beneath Your Beautiful)

Comment: Use the return value of `strstr` to check whether there is a letter before or after the search word.

Comment: Keep the result of strstr and test if previous char or next char is letter or separator . Pay attention to check if at start or end of string.

Comment: If you like to learn something most valuable, look up "regular expressions". It might feel a bit overwhelming, but you will use them in the future, for sure. Start as early as possible to learn the good stuff.